# reading string from a file in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a .kla file that has 2 variables (Name,ID) and I need to get their valuables and combine them to define a new name for a new file (Name_ID.kla) to be saved.

```
Name "Jon";
ID 1234;
```

I m really thankful for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

set INPUT=a.txt

for /f delims^=^"^ tokens^=2 %%a in ('findstr /i "Name" "%INPUT%"') do set NAME=%%a
for /f "tokens=2 delims=; " %%b in ('findstr /i "ID" "%INPUT%"') do set ID=%%b

set FNAME=%NAME%_%ID%.kla
echo %FNAME%
```

a.txt contains 2 lines:

```
Name "Jon";
ID 1234;
```

output:

```
Jon_1234.kla
```

credit: rkagerer's answer in [Escaping double-quote in delims](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13217838/452281)

Comment: my dear can u help me plz regarding this post? thanks alot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26315853/read-the-file-names-of-all-kla-files-in-a-directory-rename-them-and-move-them

Comment: my dear, there is error: FINDSTR: Cannot open  C:\TSData\Klarf\NAC_01112_3.kla. can u tell why plz?

Comment: Make sure the filename is inside double-quotes.

Comment: Tq my dear for ur attention