# Read the file names of all *.kla files in a directory, rename them and move them to a new directory by batch

Tags: batch-file

I would like to read the name of all *.kla files from a directory (C:\TSData\Klarf) and change their names and then move them to a new directory (E:\MESSDAT\DATEN\Klatencor\Klarf).

For file name renaming, in each .kla file, there are two variables that i need to get their values: (for example)
    LotID "N_123"; Slot 1;
and combine these variables like this: LotID_Slot.kla to make a new name.

I wrote this code but shows this error: "~nxi was unexpected at this time"

```
@echo off
setlocal  enableDelayedExpansion
set "LotID="
set "Slot="

:: Finding the name of *.kla files in C:\TSData\Klarf\
for /f %%l  in ('dir /b C:\TSData\Klarf\*.kla ') do (
echo %%l
:: Finding LotID, Slot in each .kla file
for /R C:\TSData\Klarf\ %%i in (*.*) do echo %%~nxi
  for /f "usebackq tokens=1,*" %%a in (
    "C:\TSData\Klarf\%%l"
) do for %%c in (%%b) do set "%%a=%%~c"
   move /-y "C:\TSData\Klarf\%%l" "E:\MESSDAT\DATEN\Klatencor\Klarf"
   ren E:\MESSDAT\DATEN\Klatencor\Klarf\%%l "%LotID%_%Slot%.kla"
)
```

Consider that in C:\TSData\Klarf\ there is a file name= 1.kla after execution of path file this file will be renamed to k1_1.kla (because for this file we have LotID=k1, Slot=1) and will move to new directory called E:\MESSDAT\DATEN\Klatencor\Klarf\ with its new name (k1_1.kla).

I dont know why this following For works well alone for a clear .kla file.

```
:: Finding LotID, Slot in each .kla file
for /R C:\TSData\Klarf\ %%i in (*.*) do echo %%~nxi
  for /f "usebackq tokens=1,*" %%a in (
    "C:\TSData\Klarf\K.kla"
) do for %%c in (%%b) do set "%%a=%%~c"
   move /-y "C:\TSData\Klarf\k.kla" "E:\MESSDAT\DATEN\Klatencor\Klarf"
   ren E:\MESSDAT\DATEN\Klatencor\Klarf\k.kla "%LotID%_%Slot%.kla"
```

Please kindly help me.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: you forgot to double the percent-sign for your second `for`loop: `%%i`, `%%~nxi`

Comment: thanks my dear for ur attention, i applied what u told me. However, after moving a .kla file to a new directory its name is not changed correctly. The file name becomes _. kla. i think these variables (LotID,SLOT) are null. whats problem dear?

Comment: You have to enclose environment variables in exclamation marks instead of percent signs to use delayed environment variable expansion as needed in `IF` and `FOR` blocks. Open a command prompt window, enter `set /?`, and read all help pages output in the window. Please edit your question and add a list of file names in `C:\TSData\Klarf` before batch execution, and two more lists showing the file names in directories `C:\TSData\Klarf` and `E:\MESSDAT\DATEN\Klatencor\Klarf` after batch execution. Otherwise we have no chance to find out what your batch code should really do.

Comment: @Stephen  thanks my dear for ur attention, i applied what u told me. However, after moving a .kla file to a new directory its name is not changed correctly. The file name becomes _. kla. i think these variables (LotID,SLOT) are null. whats problem dear? –

Comment: @Mofi tq for ur attention. Consider that in C:\TSData\Klarf\ there is a file name= 1.kla after execution of path file this file will be renamed to k1_1.kla (because for this file we have LotID=k1, Slot=1) and will move to new directory called E:\MESSDAT\DATEN\Klatencor\Klarf\ with its new name (k1_1.kla).Thanks for ur help :)

Comment: We now have 3 versions of this batch. The current version has `$%~nxi` which should be `%%~nxi` **but** I suspect that the problem is actually with the `:: comment` style - actually a broken-label which is terminating the `for...%%l...` loop. Try replacing that with `rem comment`

Comment: @Magoo thanks 4 your attention, i already updated the code but still i can't read value of LotID, Slot in a .kla file. this following code works well alone when i do not include the first>  for /f %%l  in  ('dir /b C:\TSData\Klarf\*.kla ') do ( in my code. why my dear?                                        for /R C:\TSData\Klarf\ %%i in (*.*) do echo %%~nxi
  for /f "usebackq tokens=1,*" %%a in (
    "C:\TSData\Klarf\%%l"
) do for %%c in (%%b) do set "%%a=%%~c"
   move /-y "C:\TSData\Klarf\%%l" "E:\MESSDAT\DATEN\Klatencor\Klarf"
   ren E:\MESSDAT\DATEN\Klatencor\Klarf\%%l "%LotID%_%Slot%.kla"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
setlocal  enableDelayedExpansion
set "LotID="
set "Slot="
:: Settings for OP's version
SET "sourcedir=C:\TSData\Klarf"
SET "destdir=E:\MESSDAT\DATEN\Klatencor\Klarf"
:: Overriding settings for Magoo's setup
SET "sourcedir=U:\TSData\Klarf"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"

:: Finding the name of *.kla files in C:\TSData\Klarf\
for /f "delims=" %%l in ('dir /b "%sourcedir%\*.kla" ') do (
 echo %%l
 REM
 REM NOTE USE OF REM NOT :: WITHIN A BLOCK (FOR..%%l)
 REM
 REM Finding LotID, Slot in each .kla file
 REM
 REM No idea why this line is here for /R "%sourcedir%" %%i in (*.*) do echo %%~nxi
 REM
 for /f "usebackq tokens=1,*" %%a in (
    "%sourcedir%\%%l"
  ) do for %%c in (%%b) do set "%%a=%%~c"
 REM
 REM Note that MOVE across devices (C: to E: will COPY AFAIAA)
 REM
 ECHO(move /-y "%sourcedir%\%%l" "%destdir%\"
 REM
 REM Note use of !var! not %var% to access changed values LotID and Slot, not original values
 REM
 ECHO(ren "%destdir%\%%l" "!LotID!_!Slot!.kla"
 ECHO(move /-y "%sourcedir%\%%l" "%destdir%\!LotID!_!Slot!.kla"
)
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances. I've set them as I customarily do, and overridden the setting with values to suit my system.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

The required MOVE commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.  Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`)

As I commented, the `:: comment` should be replaced by `rem comment` within a block.

You haven't indicated how the new name is constructed. "LotID" and "Slot" seem to appear from nowhere. On analysing your code, it would appear that lines similar to

```
LotID is often k1
Slot might be 1
```

may appear in your `.kla` file. Your method of setting these variable may or may not be valid - without sample data, it's not possible to tell.

I believe that attempting to `move` files from one device to another will in fact `copy` the file, so the original file would stay in its original place and a copy would appear with the new name in the destination. I've aded an extra line to show how this could be done in a single line rather than two.

Here's the code I used to create a `.kla` file for testing, since you haven't provided sample data:

```
FOR %%a IN ("LotID perhaps is Z99"
"Slot is arguably 6") DO ECHO %%~a
)>"%sourcedir%\two.kla"
```

As for the reason for the `for /r` - heaven alone knows what this is meant to do!

---

Edit : to fix filenames with spaces...the `for...%%l` has the `"delims="` option added.

Filenames tested include :

```
"%sourcedir%\1.kla"
"%sourcedir%\1 that is one.kla"
"%sourcedir%\t(w)o.kla"
"%sourcedir%\t(w, and a bit)o.kla"
"%sourcedir%\t(w,hree)o.kla"
```

Where `sourcedir` itself contained a space.

Please indicate file and directorynames failing if you find others...

Comment: I am really thankful for your kindness. God bless u. My patch finally works. but one issue is that how can i handle if the file names has these character> (,) ?

Comment: I really appreciate. It works my dears. Thanks again :) All the best.