# Extracting particular string based on key from json file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

i run a command(`mycommand`) in windows which returns a json file on that i do the following operation

```
<mycommand> | findstr /r InstanceId >instance.txt
```

which returns `"InstanceId": "i-59df8e93",` as output. now what i wish to do is i just want the part that will always be after the `InstanceId:` and before the `,`.

How to do that in windows command prompt ?

EDIT 1: i have made progress till here,

**content of Instance1.txt** :

```
   "InstanceId": "i-59df8e93"
```

**I used the following command :**

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=:" %G IN (instance1.txt)  DO @echo %G %I> instance1.txt
```

**it returns**  `"InstanceId"`

i wanted these two tokens to in different variables. so that i can extract `i-59df8e93`. How to proceed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reference [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)

Source file:

```
"InstanceId": "i-59df8e93"
```

You need to use `"` as a delimeter and extract the **3rd** token.

The easiest wasy to use `"` as a delimeter is by using the following 'trick' (reference answer to [Escaping double-quote in `delims` option of `for /F`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13217838/3536342) by [rkagerer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589059/rkagerer)):

1. use `^` (as long as it is not present in the file) as the delimeter
2. swap the order of `delims` and `tokens`

Now you can use the following command to extract `i-59df8e93`:

```
for /f delims^=^"^ tokens^=3 %a in (instance.txt) do @echo %a
```

Output:

```
i-59df8e93
```

Note: I've used `instance.txt` as this file was the output of the original command.

To add this value to `instance1.txt`:

```
for /f delims^=^"^ tokens^=3 %a in (instance.txt) do @echo %a > instance1.txt
```

Putting it all together in a batch file:

```
<mycommand> | findstr /r InstanceId >instance.txt
for /f delims^=^"^ tokens^=3 %%a in (instance.txt) do @%echo %%a > instance1.txt
```

Note: In a batch file you need to replace `%` with `%%`.