# Escaping FOR /F options

Tags: batch-file

I am new to batch scripting.I was going through a tutorial and then tried writing a code.I was looking for a better option and i found the below

```
 for /f usebackq^ tokens^=2^ delims^=^" %%A in ("final.txt") do echo %%A
```

Can someone please explain the role of `^` in usebackq , `^=2^` in tokens and `^=^"` in delims?

Comment: Could you add a link to the tutorial in your question? The ^ sign is used to escape special characters but I don't know why you would use it like this.

Comment: This code is used to have the delimiter be a double quote.

Comment: An explanation can be found at [Escaping double-quote in `delims` option of `for /F`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7516064/463115)

Comment: Basically ^ escapes any one character so you don't need to enclose things with spaces in double queotes.

Comment: In the command you gave, theres no opening double quote before the parameters.